# Left join different table and count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables. Following are sample tables for easy reference.

```
drop table if exists #itemmaster
drop table if exists #sales
drop table if exists #transfer

CREATE TABLE #itemmaster(ItemID float, ItemName varchar(10))
insert into #itemmaster values
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C'),
(4,'D'),
(5,'E'),
(6,'F'),
(7,'G'),
(8,'H')

CREATE TABLE #sales(ItemID float)
insert into #sales values
(1),
(5),
(2),
(5),
(5),
(4),
(1),
(1),
(8),
(4),
(7)

CREATE TABLE #transfer(ItemID float)
insert into #transfer values
(2),
(5),
(5),
(4),
(1),
(1),
(7)
```

**I am trying to get following result.**

```
+--------+--------------+-----------------+
| ItemID | CountOfSales | CountOfTransfer |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+
|      1 |            3 |               2 |
|      2 |            1 |               1 |
|      3 |            0 |               0 |
|      4 |            2 |               1 |
|      5 |            3 |               2 |
|      6 |            0 |               0 |
|      7 |            1 |               1 |
|      8 |            1 |               0 |
```

I am running following query but it is giving me incorrect result.
I am not sure why left join with count calculation giving me wrong output.
Please help to resolve and understand the method.

```
select i.ItemID, count(s.itemid) as CountOfSales, count(t.itemid) as CountOfTransfer
from #itemmaster I
left join #sales S on i.itemid = S.itemid
left join #transfer T on i.itemid = t.itemid
group by i.itemid
```

Comment: Learn to debug your own code. Remove the aggregates and just select the columns that you refer to within the aggregates. Then filter the resultset for a particular ItemID value you know to be incorrect. Now do what you ask the engine to do and count the values. Do you see the reason behind the unexpected counts?

Comment: As a side note, I'm assuming this is just fake data that you made up for this example. However, I would strongly suggest that you **do not** use FLOAT, nor any of the floating-point/approximate/non-integer/complex-number data types for database keys. For numeric-based IDs, use the "whole-number" types `BIGINT`, `INT`, `SMALLINT` and `TINYINT`. If you want to get _fancy_ you can use `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, but the integer types should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where correlated subqueries can be quite handy:

```
 select i.*,
           (select count(*)
            from #sales S 
            where i.itemid = S.itemid
           ) as CountOfSales,
           (select count(*)
            from #transfer t
            where i.itemid = t.itemid
           ) as CountOfTransfer
    from #itemmaster i;
```

If `#sales` and `#transfer` have indexes on `itemid`, then this is also probably the fastest solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a few sub-queries to simplify your Sales and Transfer tables that you want to join to, and then LEFT JOIN those results back to your item table. In this code I'm using CTEs (Common Table Expressions) rather than just sub-queries in the main FROM statement for readability and cleanliness.

```sql
-- First get the Sales totals
WITH SalesTotals AS (
    SELECT
        S.ItemID,
        COUNT(*) AS SaleCount
    FROM
        #sales AS S
    GROUP BY
        S.ItemID
),
-- Then get the Transfer Totals
TransferTotals AS (
    SELECT
        T.ItemID,
        COUNT(*) AS TransferCount
    FROM
        #transfer AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.ItemID
)
-- Join the SalesTotals and TransferTotals to the ItemMaster table
SELECT 
    I.ItemID,
    ISNULL(ST.SaleCount, 0) AS CountOfSales,
    ISNULL(TT.TransferCount, 0) AS CountOfTransfer
FROM
    #itemmaster AS I
    LEFT JOIN SalesTotals AS ST ON I.ItemID = ST.ItemID
    LEFT JOIN TransferTotals AS TT ON I.ItemID = TT.ItemID
```